# Drop wizard exception, don’t log stack trace

Tags: java, exception, stack-trace, dropwizard

In Dropwizard a custom exception is being thrown. The exception returns a 404 to the request and logs a full stack trace. How do you only send the response but not record the stacktrace to the server logs?

```
public class MyExcpetion extends BadRequestException {
```

Answer (score 0):

To you have to throw the `MyExcpetion` instance? You could throw a `BadRequestException`  instead that includes the `MyExcpetion` cause.

```java
throw new BadRequestException(myExceptionCause);
```